# Noisy Webdriver output during automated tests

Tags: ruby, webdriver, capybara

While running a cucumber-based test, I used the -b commend to get more information on the error. Now it seems that my webdriver will not go back to quiet mode.

Here's my support file:

```
    require 'capybara'
    require 'capybara/cucumber'
    require 'rspec'
    require 'selenium/webdriver'
    #require 'capybara/rails'

    def snore(location)
      x = 0
      timeout = 120
      while (page.has_css?(location) == false) && (x < timeout)
        sleep(1)
        x = x + 1
        puts x
        puts page.has_css?(location)
      end
    end

    def eventday
      now = Time.now
      today = 0
      if now.day.to_i > 27
        today = 15
      else
        today = now.day.to_s
      end
      return today.to_s
    end

    def monthup
      now = Time.now
      monthtime = 0
      if now.day.to_i > 27
        monthtime = 1500000
      else
        monthtime = 3000000
      end
      return monthtime.to_i
    end

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome #chrome|firefox|internet_explorer
#caps.version = "8"
#caps.platform = :WINDOWS

Capybara.server_port = 3001
Capybara.app_host = "http://www.google.com"
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.ignore_hidden_elements = true
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app,
    :browser => :chrome #chrome|firefox|internet_explorer
    #,
    #:url => "localhost:4444/wd/hub",
    #:desired_capabilities => ("chrome.binary", "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser")
    )
end
```

Here's some of the output I'm seeing:

```
[8.261][INFO]: received WebDriver request: POST /session/1bdb4fe1ae6d3bef1f6e4299c3b3/url
   "url": "http://example.org"
}
[8.267][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[8.283][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[8.377][INFO]: waiting for pending navigations...
[0703/152133:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(479)] Error: surface has zero area 0 x 0
[0703/152133:ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(547)] Failed to resize pbuffer.
[10.866][INFO]: done waiting for pending navigations
[10.866][INFO]: sending WebDriver response: 200 {
   "sessionId": "1bdb4fe1ae6d3bef1f6e4299c3b3",
   "status": 0,
   "value": null
```